# How do I add colour to a QNX terminal?

Tags: colors, ksh, qnx-neutrino

I'm connecting to QNX Neutrino over SSH with PuTTY 0.62.

I've enabled "Allow terminal to specify ASCI colours", and "Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode".

How do I get my terminal (qansi-m) to add colour to the output text?

Comment: Could someone explain why it's off topic? This question relates to "software tools commonly used by programmers" and is a "practical, answerable problems that [is] unique to the programming profession" (from FAQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add colours by using the following when using `echo`:

The graphic rendition codes are as follows:

```
Number  Meaning
0       All attributes off (except charset (10, 11, 12))
1       Bold
2       Half intensity (default to cyan on color screen)
4       Underline (default to red on color screen)
5       Blink
7       Reverse
9       Invisible
10      Exit alternate char set (GR & GL are restored)
11      Enter PC-lower char set (GR & GL are ASCII; C0 & C1 are PC_LO except for ESC)
12      Enter PC-higher char set (GR, C1 & GL, C0 are PC_HI except for ESC)
21      Normal intensity (un-Bold)
22      Normal intensity (un-Half intensity)
24      Disable underline
25      Disable blink
27      Disable reverse
29      Visible
30-37   Set foreground color (30+color_number, see below)
39      Set foreground to saved
40-47   Set background color (40+color_number, see below)
49      Set background to saved
```

The color codes are as follows:

```
colour_num  Description
0           Black
1           Red
2           Green
3           Brown
4           Blue
5           Violet
6           Cyan
7           White
```

**Syntax:**

```
{CSI}<setting1>;<setting2>m
```

CSI in octal is \0233, so to print bold text (1) with a red foreground (31), you'd do:

```
echo "\023331;1m"
```

[Reference](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/d/devc-con.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the programs you run on the Neutrino (including the shell) to send the necessary ANSI escape sequences. `sshd` can't intercept and modify the terminal output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think the shell I'm using is designed to be colourful, I think I'm best manually adding colour using escape sequences. I've modified the scope of my question.

Comment: If you want your shell's prompt to be colourful, you can add the relevant escape sequences to your `PS1`.